# Circular Picture on D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a rounded picture using D3JS in a graph.
Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vsvuyusg/1/

As you can see, on line 99 we have this code (that supposed to work):

```
var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

node.each(function(d) {
    var _node = d3.select(this);

  defs.append("svg:pattern")
      .attr("id", "circlePicture_" + d.name)
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) {
          var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
          var imagePath =
                 "http://www.bigbiz.com/bigbiz/icons/ultimate/Comic/Comic"
                 + rnd.toString() + ".gif";
          console.log(imagePath);
          return imagePath;
      })
      .attr("width", 12)
      .attr("height", 12)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

  _node.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 12)
            .attr("cy", 12)
      .attr("r", 12)
      .style("fill", "url(#circlePicture_" + d.name + ")")
});
```

I create a pattern for each image, setting the node name on it and use it to fill a circle appended to the node (using the same node name as ref).

I've noticed that after the code executes, I cannot find any `def` or `pattern` tags inside the `svg` tag. Although, the `console.log` that we have when creating the patterns execute entirely.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height/width attribute on the `pattern` node:

```
defs.append("svg:pattern")
  .attr("id", "circlePicture_" + d.name)
  .attr("width", 12)
  .attr("height", 12)
  .append("svg:image")
  ...
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsvuyusg/2/).